# Washer for Leaking Shower Tap

Tags: shower, leak, faucet

I have water leaking from my shower and I am not quite sure how to go about fixing it. See attached pictures for my shower handles. Could anyone tell me what kind of system this is so that I can pull up any manuals and try to figure this out? There are not brand markings in the fixtures unfortunately. Greatly appreciate any inputs.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: where is it leaking exactly

Comment: Will probably need to take one apart and bring it to your local plumbing shop.  Unless the make is quite odd, most of the insides are common enough to get a match.

Comment: If they're both the same age it might be a good time to replace both of them while you're at it.

Comment: @Ruskes - water is leaking through the faucets (shower or the tap below depending on which one is water is being directed to)